# Access global variable in runtime-linked dll

Tags: c++, dll

I need to access some legacy dll's global variable at run time. I do have the header file for the global variable definition

```
struct CmpSys
   {
    public:
       static const int NAME_LEN = 21;
       char szNam[NAME_LEN]  ;         // user defined system name
   }
```

The global variable is packed in a c++.dll as

```
CmpSys** gapCmpSys
```

In my cpp file I use

```
hDEWModelDll = LoadLibrary(L"DEWModel.dll");

(CmpSys**) ptrCmpSys = (CmpSys**)GetProcAddress(hDEWModelDll, "gapCmpSys");
```

The debugger shows that the ptrCmpSys has a valid address (not null), but the content is all wrong.

if I write

```
ptrCmpSys[0]->szNam
```

I will get strange charater string.

what should I do?

Comment: is your variable called `globalCmpSys` or `gapCmpSys` (ie. is is a typo in your question or you call `GetProcAddress` with a symbol name that does not match your variable name)?

Comment: Yes, looks like a typo. Waiting for OP to confirm.